# Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following: <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current delete exists prior

Tags: sql, procedure

Trying to create a procedure that produces a random full day menu.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE MC_CREATE_RANDOM_MENU(IN P_DAY_NUMBER INT)
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM MC_90_DAYS_MENU WHERE Day_Number = P_DAY_NUMBER;
   DELETE FROM MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM WHERE Day_Number = P_DAY_NUMBER;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Breakfast', Item FROM Breakfast ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Breakfast', Item FROM `Coffee & Tea` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Lunch', Item FROM Salads ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Lunch', Item FROM 
       (SELECT * FROM `Beef & Pork` UNION SELECT * FROM `Chicken & Fish`) AS T
       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Lunch', Item FROM Beverages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   IF RAND() < 0.5 THEN
       INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
       SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Lunch', Item FROM Desserts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   END IF;
   IF RAND() < 0.5 THEN
       INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
       SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Afternoon Snack', Item FROM `Smoothies & Shakes` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   ELSE
       INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
       SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Afternoon Snack', Item FROM `Coffee & Tea` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
       INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
       SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Afternoon Snack', Item FROM `Snacks & Sides` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   END IF;
   -- Dinner
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Dinner', Item FROM 
       (SELECT * FROM `Beef & Pork` UNION SELECT * FROM `Chicken & Fish`) AS T
       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
   SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Dinner', Item FROM Beverages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   IF RAND() < 0.5 THEN
       INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU_ITEM (Day_Number, Meal_Type, Item)
       SELECT P_DAY_NUMBER, 'Dinner', Item FROM 
           (SELECT * FROM Desserts UNION SELECT * FROM `Coffee & Tea`) AS T
           ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
   END IF;
   INSERT INTO MC_90_DAYS_MENU (Day_Number)
```

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask] please.

Comment: Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Keyword IN comes after the parameter:

```
MC_CREATE_RANDOM_MENU(P_DAY_NUMBER IN INT)
```

Note IN is the default so you really don't need it in your example.